# Direct3D Rendering Cookbook, CMO 3D Models?

Tags: c#, rendering, directx, direct3d

Okay so i got the book "Direct3D Rendering Cookbook" and it's great,

But now when i wanted to import my custom models, I saw it needs to be a CMO file?

What is that format, and can I somehow convert my fbx or obj to it?

I tried:

- Exporting in blender
- Just renaming the file lol
- Googling

None of which worked :<

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2012 or later, it has a "Content Processing Pipeline" that will convert WaveFront OBJ or Autodesk FBX into CMO files.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/set-up-visual-studio-for-game-development).

The **meshconvert** tool which is part of the **DirectXMesh** project on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMesh) will also produce CMO files.

Other content types produced by Visual Studio:

- `DDS` files can be generated from various file formats using the *Image Content Pipeline*. This makes use of a version of [DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXtex).
- `CSO` files are generated from HLSL files using the HLSL compiler (FXC.EXE for Shader Model 1 - 5, DXC.EXE for Shader Model 6).

> CMO files (a.k.a. Compiled Mesh Objects) are covered in detail as part of the [Visual Studio Starter Kit](http://aka.ms/vs3dkitwin) sample. I support them in the *DirectX Tool Kit* along with SDKMESH files. See [this C++ source](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/main/Src/ModelLoadCMO.cpp).